# Using linear search to check?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to compare a .txt file that has a list of words, and a String[] array that is also filled with words.

Solved thank you.

Comment: which line is the error on?

Comment: the error is on the line with "scanner.nextLine();"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're ultimately just trying to get a list of words that are in both files:

```
Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);
Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();

while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
  String s = fileReader.next();
  words.add(s);
}
fileReader.close();

Scanner otherFileReader = new Scanner(otherFile);
List<String> wordsInBothFiles = new ArrayList<>();

while (otherFileReader.hasNext()) {
  String s = otherFileReader.next();
  if (words.contains(s)) {
    wordsInBothFiles.add(s);
  }
}
otherFileReader.close();

// Do whatever it is you have to do with the shared words, like printing them:
// for (String s : wordsInBothFiles) {
//   System.out.println(s);
// }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot use Set<String>/HashSet. Any alternatives?

Comment: You could use a List/ArrayList instead, since it also has a `.contains()` method.

Comment: We also can't use List/ArrayList. I should have mentioned that sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) it will usually explain why a method throws an exception. In this case "no line was found" means you've hit the end of your file. There are two possible ways this error could come about:

```
String nextLine = scanner.nextLine(); //problem 1: reads a file with no lines
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   linearSearch(words,nextLine);
   System.out.println(nextLine);
} 
scanner.nextLine(); //problem 2: reads after there is not next line
```

Since you loop appears to be infinite I'd wager you're getting the exception from the first line and can fix it by adding the following check before `String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();`:

```
if(!scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println("empty file: "+filePath)
    return; //or break or otherwise terminate
}
```

Beyond that you may still have some other issues but hopefully this resolves your present problem.